# Getting error - Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to paginate my page using mongoose query. But getting error can't set headers after they are sent. Sort is working fine if used without paginate.

where is my mistake. what does this error mean? My code below

app.js

```
var options = {
    perPage:3,
    delta : 1,
    page:5

};
app.get("/api/Productlist",function(req,res){
    var query = ProductModel.find(function(err,items,count){
        if(err){
            var empty = {}
            res.send(JSON.stringify(empty));
            console.log("cannot finf data");
        }else{
        res.send(JSON.stringify(items));
                }           
 }).sort({"name":1})
    .paginate(options,function(err,items){
        if(err){
            console.log("Cant paginate");
        }
        console.log(items);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine it is querying only 2 records at a time .but i want to display records on my html page with page number. how to bind html body with this query.

```
ProductModel.find().paginate(2,2).
        exec(function(error,item){
            if(error){
                console.log("Error");
            }else{

                console.log(item);
                res.send(JSON.stringify(item));
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

a few things:

1) you can write res.json instead of res.send(JSON.stringify(object));

2) In your database query, your'e immediately invoking the function and sending the response before your pagination is done. I found that if your'e not intending to make your app very large scale, you can use skip and limit, here is an example, hope it helps.

```
yourModel.find().sort({name:1}).skip(0).limit(3).then(data=>{
  if(data.length === 0){
    let err = new Error();
    err.message = "cannot find data";
    err.status = 404;
    res.status(err.status).json(err);
  }
  res.json(data);
});
```

3) if you want to keep the current structure, here is an example, you need to invoke your function only once, like this, no need to find and then again paginate

```
ProductModel.find().sort({name:1}).paginate(yourOptions,function(err,items){
   console.log(items)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I used your option 3. but it is showing error ProductModel.find().sort({name:1}).paginate...  is not a function.here is my code                                                                                                             app.get("/api/Productlist",function(req,res){  ProductModel.find().sort({name:1}).paginate(options,function(err,items){
       if(err){
        console.log("cant find data");
       }else{
        res.send(JSON.stringify(items));
       }
 });
 });